# error iteration limit reached ,I'm a beginner to ngspice I'm using ngsipce by esim fossee help me out pls?

Tags: mosfet, inverter, single-phase, ngspice

[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK3Gr.png)
I m trying to single-phase bridge inverter. here I have attached the error image, Schematic, source detail(pulse generator, Dc) transient analysis time. If I'm done a mistake in any of these please address me. Thank you.
[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jehhB.png)

[image]pulse generator 1

[image]

[image]

[image]pulse genartor 2

Comment: Some times, this error occurs when parameters named itl are too low. Must see the global parameters of spice. I see also an error : matrix singular. Some times, It come when, related to a loop, there is only reactive or generators serial components. Adding defaults resistors (10 Meg, option Spice to be selected) will clear this error. What is the software name ?

Comment: Can you locate the spice source file? Is the spice source given in the error message? Try to find from the source or by some other way which node is `node 6`.